# MPU6050 connection

Tags: arduino, accelerometer

Here is what I have done...
I simply copied the simple Arduino MPU6050 code from http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050 and pasted it in my arduino uno R3, which is interfaced with GY-521 IMU....

These are the values, which I'm getting...

```
InvenSense MPU-6050
June 2012
WHO_AM_I : 68, error = 0
PWR_MGMT_2 : 0, error = 0

MPU-6050
Read accel, temp and gyro, error = 0
accel x,y,z: 1804, 1256, 15184
temperature: 27.329 degrees Celsius
gyro x,y,z : -4933, 3934, 490, 

MPU-6050
Read accel, temp and gyro, error = 0
accel x,y,z: 5580, 1760, 14720
temperature: 27.047 degrees Celsius
gyro x,y,z : -4620, 3913, 428, 

MPU-6050
Read accel, temp and gyro, error = 0
accel x,y,z: 3392, -84, 16828
temperature: 26.576 degrees Celsius
gyro x,y,z : -4559, 4073, 308, 

MPU-6050
Read accel, temp and gyro, error = 0
accel x,y,z: 5672, 352, 10612
temperature: 26.765 degrees Celsius
gyro x,y,z : -4640, 3980, 364, 

MPU-6050
Read accel, temp and gyro, error = 0
accel x,y,z: 4392, 1068, 13724
temperature: 27.000 degrees Celsius
gyro x,y,z : -4496, 3749, 380,
```

What I'm not able to figure out is that the values are either correct or not....and why is this having this much fluctuation...
The sensor is kept on my bed @stationary and though, it has these values....

I can figure out that I temp value is somewhat correct, but what about the gyro and accel value....

Please, help me to sort out this....

Comment: Is the MPU-6050 board soldered on, or just hanging off jumper wires/breadboard? I find these devices to be very "touchy" if not well connected.

Comment: The gyro readings look fairly stable, that's probably just random walk. Try taking a few readings with the board upside down, pointing straight up versus down and on the left edge versus right edge etc. Because of gravity you should get about +/- 1G on each axis doing that and it'll tell you if it's roughly working.

Answer (score 1):

Plot the value in a chart, and give the IMU a nudge. In my experience that's a great way to see if you have all your parsing/interface setup right.